# How can I fix " wait for dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess failed: No child processes E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

When I use 'sudo apt-get upgrade, I get a problem with the dpkg.

```
(Reading database ... 93929 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../motd-news-config_11ubuntu5.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking motd-news-config (11ubuntu5.7) over (11ubuntu5.4) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess failed: No child processes
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```